# Derivative "distributing" over a sum

Tags: calculus, derivatives, summation

my probability class used the following statement in a proof, where $q$ is some variable (in the context of the class - the probability of an unsuccessful outcome in the geometric distribution - but I don't feel this is relevant to the problem)
$$
\frac{d}{dq}q + \frac{d}{dq}q^2 + \frac{d}{dq}q^3 + \ldots
 = \frac{d}{dq} \left(q+q^2+q^3+ \ldots \right)
$$

Could someone point me to what this property is called and how to prove it? Thanks

Comment: This is called the additive property of derivatives, or (a special case of) the linearity of derivatives. It will be proved in any calculus book; it follows from the corresponding properties of limits. (If you're truly referring to derivatives of infinite series, then the property is mathematically more technically complicated because of the need to check convergence, but the basic idea is still the same.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called *linearity of the derivative*.

Here is the [discussion on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity_of_differentiation)

What makes your case non-trivial is that you seem to be adding an infinite number of terms, in which case the equality holds only if both sums converge...